# no applicable method for 'prep' applied to an object of class

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-recipes

I am building a custom `recipes` function and getting an error when I try to `prep()` the recipe. I get the following error:

```r
> prep(rec_obj)
Error in UseMethod("prep") : 
  no applicable method for 'prep' applied to an object of class "c('step_hai_hyperbolic', 'step')"
```

When I have the `prep.step_hai_hyperbolic()` loaded into the global environment as a function so that it shows up in the environment area of RStudio then `prep()` works just fine.

Here is the entire function and an example:

```r
step_hai_hyperbolic <- function(recipe,
                                ...,
                                role       = "predictor",
                                trained    = FALSE,
                                columns    = NULL,
                                scale_type = c("sin","cos","tan"),
                                skip       = FALSE,
                                id         = rand_id("hai_hyperbolic")
){

    terms <- recipes::ellipse_check(...)
    funcs <- c("sin", "cos", "tan")
    if (!(scale_type %in% funcs))
        rlang::abort("`func` should be either `sin`, `cos`, or `tan`")

    recipes::add_step(
        recipe,
        step_hai_hyperbolic_new(
            terms      = terms,
            role       = role,
            trained    = trained,
            columns    = columns,
            scale_type = scale_type,
            skip       = skip,
            id         = id
        )
    )
}

step_hai_hyperbolic_new <-
    function(terms, role, trained, columns, scale_type, skip, id){

        recipes::step(
            subclass   = "hai_hyperbolic",
            terms      = terms,
            role       = role,
            trained    = trained,
            columns    = columns,
            scale_type = scale_type,
            skip       = skip,
            id         = id
        )

    }

#' @export
prep.step_hai_hyperbolic <- function(x, training, info = NULL, ...) {

    #col_names <- recipes::recipes_eval_select(x$terms, training, info = info)
    col_names <- recipes::recipes_eval_select(x$terms, training, info)

    value_data <- info[info$variable %in% col_names, ]

    if(any(value_data$type != "numeric")){
        rlang::abort(
            paste0("All variables for `step_hai_hyperbolic` must be `numeric`",
                   "`integer` `double` classes.")
        )
    }

    step_hai_hyperbolic_new(
        terms      = x$terms,
        role       = x$role,
        trained    = TRUE,
        columns    = col_names,
        scale_type = x$scale_type,
        skip       = x$skip,
        id         = x$id
    )

}

#' @export
bake.step_hai_hyperbolic <- function(object, new_data, ...){

    make_call <- function(col, scale_type){
        rlang::call2(
            "hai_hyperbolic_vec",
            x              = rlang::sym(col)
            ,  .scale_type = scale_type
            , .ns          = "healthyR.ai"
        )
    }

    grid <- expand.grid(
        col                = object$columns
        , scale_type       = object$scale_type
        , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )

    calls <- purrr::pmap(.l = list(grid$col, grid$scale_type), make_call)

    # Column Names
    newname <- paste0(grid$col, "_", grid$scale_type)
    calls   <- recipes::check_name(calls, new_data, object, newname, TRUE)

    tibble::as_tibble(dplyr::mutate(new_data, !!!calls))

}

#' @export
print.step_hai_hyperbolic <-
    function(x, width = max(20, options()$width - 35), ...) {
        cat("Hyperbolic transformation on ", sep = "")
        printer(
            # Names before prep (could be selectors)
            untr_obj = x$terms,
            # Names after prep:
            tr_obj = names(x$columns),
            # Has it been prepped?
            trained = x$trained,
            # An estimate of how many characters to print on a line:
            width = width
        )
        invisible(x)
    }

#' @rdname required_pkgs.healthyR.ai
#' @export
required_pkgs.step_hai_hyperbolic <- function(x, ...) {
    c("healthyR.ai")
}
```

Here is an example of it not working without everything loaded into the current session environment:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(healthyR.ai)

len_out    = 10
by_unit    = "month"
start_date = as.Date("2021-01-01")

data_tbl <- tibble(
    date_col = seq.Date(from = start_date, length.out = len_out, by = by_unit),
    a    = rnorm(len_out),
    b    = runif(len_out)
)

rec_obj <- recipe(a ~., data = data_tbl) %>%
    step_hai_hyperbolic(b, scale_type = "sin") %>%
    step_hai_hyperbolic(b, scale_type = "cos")
```

Output of the rec_obj to the console:

```r
> rec_obj
Recipe

Inputs:

      role #variables
   outcome          1
 predictor          2

Operations:

Hyperbolic transformation on b
Hyperbolic transformation on b
```

The error at time of prep:

```r
> prep(rec_obj)
Error in UseMethod("prep") : 
  no applicable method for 'prep' applied to an object of class "c('step_hai_hyperbolic', 'step')"
```

Session Info:

```r
> sessioninfo::session_info()
- Session info  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 hash: credit card, keyboard, flag: South Africa

 setting  value
 version  R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
 os       Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)
 system   x86_64, mingw32
 ui       RStudio
 language (EN)
 collate  English_United States.1252
 ctype    English_United States.1252
 tz       America/New_York
 date     2021-11-05
 rstudio  1.4.1717 Juliet Rose (desktop)
 pandoc   NA

- Packages ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package      * version    date (UTC) lib source
 assertthat     0.2.1      2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 backports      1.3.0      2021-10-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 broom        * 0.7.10     2021-10-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 cellranger     1.1.0      2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 class          7.3-19     2021-05-03 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 cli            3.1.0      2021-10-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 codetools      0.2-18     2020-11-04 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 colorspace     2.0-2      2021-06-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 crayon         1.4.2      2021-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 DBI            1.1.1      2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 dbplyr         2.1.1      2021-04-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 dials        * 0.0.10     2021-09-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 DiceDesign     1.9        2021-02-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 digest         0.6.28     2021-09-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 dplyr        * 1.0.7      2021-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 ellipsis       0.3.2      2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 fansi          0.5.0      2021-05-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 forcats      * 0.5.1      2021-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 foreach        1.5.1      2020-10-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 fs             1.5.0      2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 furrr          0.2.3      2021-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 future         1.23.0     2021-10-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 future.apply   1.8.1      2021-08-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 generics       0.1.1      2021-10-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 ggplot2      * 3.3.5      2021-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 globals        0.14.0     2020-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 glue           1.4.2      2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 gower          0.2.2      2020-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 GPfit          1.0-8      2019-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 gtable         0.3.0      2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 hardhat        0.1.6      2021-07-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 haven          2.4.3      2021-08-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 healthyR.ai  * 0.0.2.9000 2021-11-05 [1] local
 hms            1.1.1      2021-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 httr           1.4.2      2020-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 infer        * 1.0.0      2021-08-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 ipred          0.9-12     2021-09-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 iterators      1.0.13     2020-10-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 jsonlite       1.7.2      2020-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 lattice        0.20-44    2021-05-02 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 lava           1.6.10     2021-09-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 lhs            1.1.3      2021-09-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 lifecycle      1.0.1      2021-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 listenv        0.8.0      2019-12-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 lubridate      1.8.0      2021-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 magrittr       2.0.1      2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 MASS           7.3-54     2021-05-03 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 Matrix         1.3-4      2021-06-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 modeldata    * 0.1.1      2021-07-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 modelr         0.1.8      2020-05-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 munsell        0.5.0      2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 nnet           7.3-16     2021-05-03 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 parallelly     1.28.1     2021-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 parsnip      * 0.1.7      2021-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 pillar         1.6.4      2021-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 pkgconfig      2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 plyr           1.8.6      2020-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 pROC           1.18.0     2021-09-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 prodlim        2019.11.13 2019-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 purrr        * 0.3.4      2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 R6             2.5.1      2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 Rcpp           1.0.7      2021-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 readr        * 2.0.2      2021-09-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 readxl         1.3.1      2019-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 recipes      * 0.1.17     2021-09-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 reprex         2.0.1      2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 rlang          0.4.12     2021-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 rpart          4.1-15     2019-04-12 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 rsample      * 0.1.0      2021-05-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 rstudioapi     0.13       2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 rvest          1.0.2      2021-10-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 scales       * 1.1.1      2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 sessioninfo    1.2.1      2021-11-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 stringi        1.7.5      2021-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 stringr      * 1.4.0      2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 survival       3.2-11     2021-04-26 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 tibble       * 3.1.5      2021-09-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 tidymodels   * 0.1.4      2021-10-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 tidyr        * 1.1.4      2021-09-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 tidyselect     1.1.1      2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 tidyverse    * 1.3.1      2021-04-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 timeDate       3043.102   2018-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 tune         * 0.1.6      2021-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 tzdb           0.2.0      2021-10-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 utf8           1.2.2      2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 vctrs          0.3.8      2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 withr          2.4.2      2021-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 workflows    * 0.2.4      2021-10-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
 workflowsets * 0.1.0      2021-07-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 xml2           1.3.2      2020-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
 yardstick    * 0.0.8      2021-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)

 [1] C:/Users/Steve/Documents/R/win-library/4.1
 [2] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.0/library

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can't you do `setGeneric("prep", "c('step_hai_hyperbolic', 'step')", function(x, training, info = NULL, ...) { function body goes here })` ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that, this is the first recipe I've written and that is not in the recipes webpage example for making a custom recipe. Should I drop the prep portion inside of where you have function body goes here?

Comment: Yes, you could try dropping the function body for `prep.step_hai_hyperbolic` in there.

Comment: When I take a look at other packages I do not see this sort of thing going on, example tidytext, timetk etc.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `recipes` ecosystem, but the error is coming from the S3 system being unable to dispatch on the class of `c('step_hai_hyperbolic', 'step')`. I'll look into it.

Comment: may be an issue with recipes then because when you call recipes::add_step that is a wrapper around a recipes recipe constructor, thank you for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@importFrom recipes prep bake` had to be added to the .R file

Comment: Where exactly would you put that?

Comment: in the file that houses the function see here https://github.com/spsanderson/healthyR.ai/blob/master/R/step-hai-winsorized-truncate.R line 79